# Extract a numeric substring and another line as variables from multi-line text file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, ocr

I'm writing a bash shell script that I hope to ultimately use to automate the naming and 'attachment' of scanned documents to our db. The script OCR's a section of the first page of the pdf and outputs a text file containing three lines; a name, unique id, and a datetime string:

Smith, John
Case #: 234567 ( )
09/04/2013 11:34 AM

What I'd like to do is end up with two seperate strings as variables, **"Smith, John"** and **"234567"**. I'm looking for help using regex with sed/awk/etc to extract this number. One issue is that the OCR will rarely output strings like:

```
"Case #2 234567 ( )"
```

or

```
"Ca$e # 2234567 ( 7"
```

So I'm thinking to take the only last 6-digits in the string, since only maybe 1 in 10,000+ of these ever get the last 6-digits read incorrectly. This unique ID is only 6 digits, and is always between 200000-999999. I'm learning regex, but it's slow going. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:
For now I am using:

```
casename="$(cat test.txt | sed '1!d')"
casenum="$(cat test.txt | sed -n -r 's/.*([0-9]{6}).*/\1/p')"
echo ${casenum} ${casename}
234567 Smith, John
```

Any input for why this might not be a good way to do it, or what could be improved is (very) welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might try this Regex (`BRE`):

```
[2-9][0-9]\{5\}\>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex for the second line:

```
^.*(\d{6})[^\d].*$
```

Here, **the first named sub-group** would denote the digits of interest.

For example, using Notepad++,

1. Orginal text:[image]
2. *Replace* options:[image]
3. Resulting text:[image]

The regex should remain more or less the same across environments. You might need to simply change the way the named subexpression (`$1` here) is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use something like this untested but somewhat-syntactically-valid snippet:

```
shopt -s extglob
declare -a cases
for casefile in casefiles/*
do
 name=""
 while read l
 do
  if [[ -z "$name" ]]
  then
   [[ "$l" == @(*, *) ]] && name=$l
  elif [[ "$l" == +([0-9]) ]]
  then
   after=${l#*[2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}
   l=${l%$after}
   l=${l#${l%[2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}}
   if [[ "$l" == @([2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) ]]
   then
    cases[$l]=$name
   fi
   name=""
  fi
 done < $casefile
done
```

The "hard part" prunes the first 6-digit number in your range and everything after it, then removes what's left (the stuff before the number) from the line.  Then it removes the number from the beginning of the string, and removes what's left (the part after the number) from the end.  If what's left is a 6-digit number in your range, it uses that as the index and the case name as the value in an array which you can later iterate over.

The rest should be pretty straightforward. :)  If this doesn't quite work as expected, I blame the fact that I mostly use ksh, not bash. ;)